# Testing floating point numbers equality

Tags: fortran, mingw

I am using gfortran in MinGW under Windows 7 (32bit) to compile Fortran code. Here is the minimal code contained in the file `testequal.f`:

```
      program testequal
      real*8 a1, a2

      a1 = 0.3d0
      a2 = 0.7d0

      write(*,*) 1.d0
      write(*,*) a1+a2
      write(*,*) a1+a2.eq.1.0
      write(*,*) a1+a2.eq.1.d0
      end
```

Compiled with

```
gfortran testequal.f -std=legacy
```

the output is:

```
1.0000000000000000
1.0000000000000000
F
F
```

But I expect the two booleans to be both `T` (true). What is the problem here?

Comment: I get T for both using `gfortran 4.4` on Scientific Linux. However, I suggest that you should probably spend some time reading [this article on floating point arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: a bit of a side point, but the whole number one is represented exactly regardless, so it does not make any difference 1.0 vs 1.d0, or even 1

Comment: @george: I tested it, and you are correct. Very interesting. Could you give me some reference for things like this? Thanks!

Comment: @KyleKanos: that looks a serious paper...

Comment: The wiki page is a tad easier to read..  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Representable_numbers.2C_conversion_and_rounding

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With rare exceptions, don't compare floating point numbers for exact equality.  The rules of finite-precision floating point arithmetic are not the same are the rules of real number arithmetic.  Compare numbers with a tolerance, e.g.,

```
sum = a1 + a2
if ( abs (sum - 1.0) < 1.0D-5 ) ...
```

Comment: In what exceptional circumstances in one allowed to compare reals?

Comment: Comparing fixed numbers on which no math has been done should be safe, especially if they're "really" integers. The representation should be consistent in both the assignment location and the test location. This is useful for detecting that a given value is the "default" (0.0, -999.0, or whatever). But the moment you do math, all bets are off!

Answer (score 4):

A proper comparison for reals should be agnostic of kind. This is a good way to compare:

```
if (abs(a1-a2) <= epsilon(a1)) print*, 'a1=a2'
```

Comment: The idea is correct, I often use something similar. It really depends what do the numbers mean and where they come from. If they are result of some computation, the error can be easily larger than the machine epsilon which is a very small number. Sometimes I use stuff like `100*epsilon(...)`. Sometimes one may care about the actual `spacing()` at `a1` and `a2`. There is no universal recipe.

Comment: Agreed. My opinion is that if there was a universal recipe it would have been implemented as an intrinsic function.

Answer (score 1):

The real issue is that 0.3 and 0.7 cannot be expressed exactly in binary.
0.3 => 0.010011001100110011.......
0.7 => 0.101100110011001100.......

When they are stored, if both are rounded up or both are rounded down, the addition of the two numbers will not get back to 1.000000000.....

This is a common error in programming simulations.  Try to have step sizes that are natural to the computer:

```
real*8 :: dt=2.0d0**(-5)
```

Negative powers of two can be represented exactly in the computer.  So  this will actually work:

```
program negative_powers
  real*8 :: dt = 2.0d0**(-8)
  real*8 :: t = 0.0d0

  do while (t .ne. 500.0d0)
     print *, t
     t = t + dt
  end do
  print *, t
end program negative_powers
```

Comment: This will work ONLY if the numbers are entered directly. But if you know them already, you need to compare them less likely. Most often you compare some results an they are always inaccurate.