# How do fortran conditional statements handle floating-point datatypes?

Tags: fortran

I have a simple `if` conditional statement that is comparing two real numbers (one is read from an array that is allocated and initialized in an imported module) that is failing when it shouldn't.

Under what circumstances might this happen?

I'm using the Intel compiler.

**Edit**:
For further clarification, I am doing something like this:

```
if (12.2272 >= -5.0000) then
  do something
else
  print *, 'fail'
endif
```

I'm getting `fail`. The same goes for when I evaluate with only `>` rather than `>=`.

Comment: Generally the reason for a comparison failing when it shouldn't is that the programmer doesn't completely understand what is going on.  Without sight of your code I won't hazard any other guess.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20764911/fortran-77-float-point-numbers-equality/

Comment: Yes, I don't understand, which is my reasoning for asking the question. I added some pseudocode to describe my problem. Thanks for the help!

Comment: The pseudocode that you have posted should `do something`.  But your problem description, especially the bit that states *one is read from an array that is allocated and initialized in an imported module* makes me suspicious that the allocation and initialisation are not working as you expect them to.  I continue to think that the issue arises from parts of your code that you (mistakenly) believe are correct but I remain unable to help further.

Comment: The allocated arrays read in from the other module are used extensively in the code I am working with without prior issue (to my knowledge), but it appears to the one at fault in my scenario. I have checked all functionality up to the point of failure with `print` statements, etc., so I was just hoping there was some known issue with conditionals statements and allocated real variables.It would be difficult to condense my code to a length and clarity that would be suiting to SO. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, you can compare floating point numbers reliably only with some tolerance, because of their inherent non-preciseness. Generally, you shouldn't compare for equality at all except some special cases, like comparing a directly read value with some small integer, typically 0.

If you did any non-trivial computing with one of the numbers, don't compare for equality at all. With some tolerance, you can use:

```
if (abs(a-b)<eps) ...
```

where eps is some small number. It can be some (even large) multiple of the `epsilon` intrinsic function result.

It's good to read some article about floating points, like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems

You can try this little program to see the typical problem with floating point numbers

```
real x
integer i

x = 0
do i = 1,10
   x = x + 0.1
end do

print *, x, x==1

end
```